# Oracle Text - Context Index Build with stored procedure is taking a long time

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2, oracle-text

i am looking for a way to do a free text search on an oracle database, i am using 11.2.0.4 currently.

After some research it appeared that Oracle Text was the way to go. i built a stored procedure that basically concatenates the column data that i want to index across multiple tables and index based off that: See some of the important commands below.

But essentially followed this document:

https://mindfabblog.wordpress.com/2012/09/11/oracle-text-multiple-columns-multiple-tables/

```
BEGIN
  CTX_DDL.create_preference('search_datastore', 'USER_DATASTORE');
  CTX_DDL.set_attribute('search_datastore', 'PROCEDURE', 'concat_cols');
END;


 CREATE INDEX "DBNAME"."SEARCH_IDX" ON "ERM2"."CUSTOMER_DATA" ("SEARCH_INDEX") 
INDEXTYPE IS "CTXSYS"."CONTEXT"  PARAMETERS ('datastore search_datastore);
```

The issue I have is that it is taking ages to build the index is there a better way of achieving what I want? or speeding my index build up?

Comment: The time it takes to build the index will be related to the number of columns you're concatenating, how much data is in those columns and how many rows in the tables. The other problem with this approach is maintaining that index. It's a CONTEXT index, so it can't be maintained transactionally.

Comment: well its a total of 4.6 million rows and about 15 columns with a max length of about 20chars in each column. I know how i am going to manage the index once it is built. its just the initial build that at its current rate would take about 3 months to complete!